# Is it possible to repeat external method calls by a user given times

Tags: java, methods

I guess this is a simple question but I can't find an answer on either Google or Stack Overflow. I am new to Java and I hope you can help me. I'm sorry in advance if I use the wrong terminology at any point when writing my question and code.

My question is **if there is any way to write a code that repeats an external method call?**

The method I am calling is `shootWeapon` which exists in a class called `Weapon`. I'm calling that method from another method called `shootWithWeapon` which exists in a class called `Soldier`. My class `Soldier` has an inventory of weapons in `ArrayList<Weapon>` called `weaponList`. I would like to write a code that repeats `listWeapon.shootWeapon()` as many times as the user given `shootWithWeapon` parameter `usedAmmo`. My current code is working but it's only decreasing the ammo with 1 (since it's specified in the `shootWeapon` method).

**This is my method in class "Soldier".**

```
public void shootWithWeapon(String weaponChoice,int usedAmmo)

int index = 0;
while(index < weaponList.size()){
Weapon listWeapon = weaponList.get(index);
String usedWeapon = listWeapon.getName(); //returns weapon name
int xBullets = weaponList.getBulletAmount(); //returns amount of bullets in object

if(weaponChoice.equals(usedWeapon) && usedAmmo < xBullets) {
listWeapon.shootWeapon(); //This is the method I want to repeat * usedAmmo
System.out.println("Your weapon have been used. You have " + weaponList.getBulletAmount() + " bullets left".); }

index++;
}
}
```

**This is the method I'm calling in class "Weapon".**

```
public void shootWeapon()
{
bulletAmount=bulletAmount - 1;
}
```

Comment: Well, you can always call a method in a loop, e.g. `for(int a = usedAmmo; a > 0; a--) { listWeapon.shootWeapon(); }`

Comment: Perhaps you need a [recursive method](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_recursion.asp) ?

Comment: @Thomas cant he use directly the number of amount as a param to his shootMethod?

Comment: @Abra Why would you think he need a recursive method?

Comment: @JawadElFou yes, that might make sense but it depends on what that method does: think of checking for a hit etc. - that would amount to a loop anyway so it's up to the OP and the question was about calling a method multiple times (I wouldn't bother with design here, that would lead to a very broad discussion) :)